# How do hybrids (half-humans and half-ghouls) rate in strength compared to normal ghouls?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In the anime series, there are several types of hybrids: artificial half-ghouls like Kaneki, biological half-ghouls like Eto and half-humans like Arima. How are they supposed to rate in strength compared to regular ghouls? Are they stronger, weaker or have equal strength? Is this stated in the series?

Comment: Hi. To the one who put up a close-vote, while the question seems opinion-based, a definite answer can be given based on information from the manga and from real-world information. As a manga reader, I don't think the answers to this question is primarily opinion-based :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biological half-ghouls are extremely rare. However,

- in the *Tokyo Ghoul* universe, they are considered an urban legend and *their strength are supposed to be superior compared to regular ghouls*
- To cite examples of their strength, Eto was an SSS rate in her Owl form and S rate without her Owl form; the Underground King waged war against humanity, prompting the creation of the CCG and V;

Artificial half-ghouls are similar.

- Looking at the list of successful artificial half-ghouls [here](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/One-eyed_ghoul), one can see in the manga that *their abilities are way above a normal ghoul*
- While not stated in the manga, I think what affects their strength is the abilities of the ghoul that they were made from (only Rize and Eto was used by Kanou to make artificial half-ghouls, who were at least S-rate ghouls)

Half-humans raised in the Sunlit Garden

- have highly developed physical capabilities. While not elaborated upon, I consider their strength still superior to normal ghouls as *most, if not all, of them were highly distinguished investigators* (as seen in their membership in [Arima Squad](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Arima_Squad))

Against each other, it would be difficult to rank hybrids as there are a lot of things to consider. However, even without official information on their ranks, strengths, etc., biology tells us that *hybrids have improved or increased function of any biological qualities*. ([Heterosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterosis)) So, it would be safe to say that **hybrid ghouls are superior to normal ghouls**.